# How to convert nested arrays to a group of one-element arrays

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic

Sorry the title isn't very clear.

What would be the best way to convert

```
[a, [b, c], [d, e, f], g]
```

(or other similarly group of nested arrays) into

```
[a, b, d, g], [a, b, e, g], [a, b, f, g], [a, c, d, g], ..., [a, c, f, g]
```

?

Comment: It can be done simply using recursion. Have you tried it. Is there any time limit constraints or what could be the size of original array.

Comment: Does it have to work for any level of nesting?

Comment: @FrankPuffer Yes.

Comment: @prabodhprakash I guessed recursion would be involved, but I would like something more concrete. As for time or size limit, no strict limits, but reasonable time/size would be nice.

Comment: @FrankPuffer -- Or rather, it should work for [a, b, c] as well as [[a,b], [c,d,e], f], but not necessarily for [[[a,b], c], d].

Comment: This looks more like a question to print all permutations, we recursively solve it - no choice. Here, we have set of characters to chose from, for each index. I think, we will have to eventually recursively solve it. Do you need help with recursive code or have you written it already.

Comment: @prabodhprakash I would need help with a concrete implementation, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you now learned Smalltalk, I suggest you take a look at a recursive solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9878747/1396822 .

or an iterative one:

[Generating all combinations from collections in Smalltalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867897/generating-all-combinations-from-collections-in-smalltalk/10878722#10878722)

You now know that it's called a cartesian product, so you shall be able to find other answers on SO.

Comment: Durr, didn't realize it was a cartesian product. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**New solution**

This is a non-recursive solution written in Smalltalk. The receiver is the collection of subsequences such as `[a, [b, c], [d, e, f], g]`. For the sake of simplicity the code below assumes that all entries in the receiver array are arrays, so the proper receiver would be `[[a], [b, c], [d, e, f], [g]]` instead, which in Smalltalk is written `#((a) (b c) (d e f) (g))`.

```
1.  selections
2.    | selections indexes index |
3.    selections := OrderedCollection new.
4.    indexes := Array new: self size withAll: 1.
5.    [| group |
6.      group := (1 to: self size) collect: [:i | (self at: i) at: (indexes at: i)].
7.      selections add: group.
8.      index := (1 to: self size)
          findLast: [:i | (indexes at: i) < (self at: i) size]
          ifAbsent: nil.
9.      index notNil]
10.       whileTrue: [
11.         indexes at: index put: (indexes at: index) + 1.
12.         index + 1 to: self size do: [:i | indexes at: i put: 1]].
13.   ^selections
```

---

**Comments**

1. Method name
2. Temporary declaration
3. Initialize the output
4. Start by selecting the first element of every subgroup
5. Do .. while
6. Collect one element from each subgroup at the current indexes
7. Keep the group just created
8. Find the last index which can be incremented
9. Stop if there is none (this will jump to 13)
10. If there is one such index...
11. Increment that index
12. Reset all following indexes to 1 (this will get back to 6)
13. Answer with the result

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familiar with smalltalk, would you mind explaining the reasoning behind the code?

Comment: @MikeEVMM See my explanations now and let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your thoroughness. Although.. I think this is not a solution for what I was asking.

`[a, [b, c, d], e]` should not produce (with `m=2`) `[[a,b], [c,d], [e]]`, but rather `[[a, b, e], [a, c, e], [a, d, e]]`.

Comment: @MikeEVMM Oops, my bad. Please take a look at my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it in python but this process can be applied to all programming language because are only two loops:

```
arr = ["a", ["b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], "g"]

first = arr[1] # b, c 
second = arr[2] # d, e, f


for j in first:
    for k in second:
        print(list((arr[0], j, k, arr[-1])))
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I'm looking for something that works for any nesting -- i.e. it the algorithm should also work for [[a, b], [c,d,e], f], for instance.